# get join value schema to use in where clause

Tags: elixir, ecto

is possible use a join value schema to use into where clause?

```
filtered = [name: "show", name: "comedy"]
query = from s in Core.Serie, join: t in assoc(s, :tags), where: ^filtered
```

the result is the next

```
#Ecto.Query<from s in Core.Serie, join: t in assoc(s, :tags),
 where: s.name == ^"show" and s.name == ^"comedy">
```

i need use tag schema to match correct records but by default use Serie schema. for example

```
#Ecto.Query<from s in Core.Serie, join: t in assoc(s, :tags),
 where: t.name == ^"show" and t.name == ^"comedy">
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `t.name == ^"show" and t.name == ^"comedy"` is what you want in the first place, mostly because it never matches (`name` cannot be both `"show"` *and* `"comedy"` simultaneously. I would guess you wanted `or` there.

For that we have [`Ecto.Query.or_where/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#or_where/3-keywords-example), one might reduce the filtered like below.

```rb
filtered = [name: "show", name: "comedy"]
query = from s in Core.Serie, join: t in assoc(s, :tags)
query =
  Enum.reduce(filtered, query, fn {key, value}, query ->
    from q in query, or_where: field(q, ^key) == ^value
  end)
```

I have not tested the code, but it should work out of the box.

---

Also, you might want to use [`Ecto.Query.API.in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#in/2) to group the filters having the same key.

Comment: yep, thanks,  i used "Enum.reduce" before, but don't solve my problem i don't need use parent query in this case is Serie, i need use the join clause value that is Tag, but i don't know how can i use it.